# How to create and use obfuscation dictionary for ProGuard

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I'm using a text file as an obfuscation dictionary for ProGuard . Path to file is correct, but ProGuard throws me error "The system cannot find a file specified". File has 100 lines with random unique values. (Seems It doesn't work with any dictionary). ProGuard 6.0. If I'm not using "Obfuscate dictionary" parameter, it works. Any idea why?